# Finding variance .

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, simulation

Suppose that $f : [0, 1] → [0, 1]$ and we wish to estimate 
$$I = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$$

Using the hit-and-miss method, we obtain the estimate

$$\hat I_{HM}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$$
where $X_1, . . . , X_n$ are an iid sample and $X_i ∼ binom(1, I)$

Using the improved Monte-Carlo method, we obtain the estimate

$$\hat I_{MC}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(U_i)$$

where $U_1, . . . , U_n$ are an iid sample of $U(0, 1)$ random variables.

Show that
$$Var (X_1) =  \int_{0}^{1}f(x) dx − (\int_{0}^{1}f(x) dx)^2$$
and that

$$Var f(U_1) =  \int_{0}^{1}f^2(x) dx − (\int_{0}^{1}f(x) dx)^2$$

I don't understand how the structure can be like that .

since $X_1 ∼ binom(1, I)$
I supposed 
$$Var (X_1)=npq=(1)(I)(1-I)$$

Comment: ...and that's exactly $\int_0^1 f(x)\; dx - \left(\int_0^1 f(x)\; dx\right)^2 = I - I^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for second part: $E [f(U)^2] = \int_0^1 f(x)^2\; dx$ by the Law of the Unconscious Statistician.